# PHP Server Creates a File That It Can't Delete

Tags: php, permissions, unlink

I originally posted a much different question because I didn't know why I couldn't unlink (delete) a file that the server had already created; I've discovered a bit more information and thus feel it is appropriate to reword my question.

The PHP script creates a file via fopen and gives the user a link to download it. After download, the script is meant to delete the file via unlink. I can't seem to get it to work. I've checked permissions, and this is what they look like for the file and the directory:

```
drwxrwxr-x+  55 root        _www    1870 Jan 31 09:49 .
-rw-r--r--    1 _www        _www     1362 Jan 30 12:46 file.csv
```

Which tells me that the _www group has read, write, and execute permissions for the directory and read and write permissions for the file (not to mention that the _www user owns the file!). And _www is the server, of course. So if the server has adequate permissions to read and write to the directory AND has adequate permissions to the file it created and owns, then why won't it delete the file? I don't get any errors in the script saying that unlink failed, but the file still persists after running the script. It doesn't seem to be necessary, but does _www need to have execute permissions as well for some reason? I doubt it.

Also, here is the code. It seems fine to me, but I could be nuts:

```
echo "<form action='' method='post'><input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete File'></form></div>";
   if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        unlink("file.csv") or die("Could not delete file! O, noes!");
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the line `var_dump(getcwd());` to your php script and compare it to typing `pwd` in shell?

Answer (score 0):

The plus at the end tells me there is some funky Linux ACLs going on.

This might help you  http://www.softpanorama.info/Commercial_linuxes/linux_acl.shtml